# How to combine . and column-wise operations in mutate_each

Tags: r, dplyr

**Problem**

I'm trying to create a function within `mutate_each`, which can work over columns of a dataframe and combine column-wise operations with cell-wise operations.

**Example**

```
> df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:10, ncol = 5))

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  3  5  7  9
2  2  4  6  8 10

> df <- df %>% mutate_each(funs(do = . - 1))   # Works fine

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  0  2  4  6  8
2  1  3  5  7  9

> df <- df %>% mutate_each(funs(do = max))     # Works fine

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  1  3  5  7  9
2  1  3  5  7  9

> df <- df %>% mutate_each(funs(do = . - max)) # Error
Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

**QUESTION**

What's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: If you're giving more than just the name of a function, you need to put a dot everywhere you need the data to go: `df %>% mutate_each(funs(do = . - max(.)))`

Comment: Thank you, this works well.

Comment: What I find confusing is that the `.` refers to a single 'cell' on the left-hand-side of `do = . - max(.)` and a whole column on the right-hand-side within `max(.)`. Could you please tell me how this works?

Comment: It's the full column in both cases; you're just subtracting a single value `max(.)` (derived from the full vector) from a vector `.`, returning a vector, i.e. `vector - func_to_make_scalar(vector) = vector`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer comes from Alistaire in his comment above:

> **Alistaire:**
>   If you're giving more than just the name of a function, you need to put a dot everywhere you need the data to go: `df %>% mutate_each(funs(do = . - max(.)))`